# How to create regular expression starting with different directory name in Python

Tags: python, regex

Currently I am taking directory path as input from the user. The path will be different for each user(dir_name will be different)

```
/file/perm/perm13/user123/dir_name/
```

while the structure inside dir_name is same for all users given as below:

```
tar1 tar2 tar3 tar4 tar5 tar6 source
```

In each tar, three folders are there: `build collateral fix` 
in collateral: I have three different files

```
 _base.txt, _fullbase.txt and _skip.txt
```

I also need corresponding .dot files from `source/projectfiles/params/tar_base.dot | tar_fullbase.dot | tar_skip.dot`

Here is what I need to do:
1. Take input from user 
2. One by one- go into the targets. (tar1 -> tar2 -> tar3 ->tar4 ->tar5)
3. For each tar, search for collateral folder 
4. and in collateral folder search for all three .txt files 
5. for each .txt file search for corresponding .dot file

currently I do following: 
I take path for txt from the user

```
txtfilepath = raw_input (" Please provide file path for the desired txt")
dotfilepath = raw_input (" Please enter corresponding .dotfilepath")
<directory path>/<tar1>/collateral/<xyz_base.txt)
```

The regex:

```
platform = re.search("?<=/collateral/).(?="_(base|fullbase|skip)\.txt)",txtfilepath).group(0)
```

can some python geek help?

Comment: doesn't sound like a proper work for regex. use `os.path.split` to handle it piece by piece. for the problem itself, should be easier to deal with using shell scripting

Comment: Thanks. I should look into os module perhaps.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr :Thanks for your suggestion. I solved the problem.